# Paraphrase request

Tags: word-choice, paraphrasing

How might you rephrase  this sentence using different words than these?

> Soil is in hydraulic near-equilibrium

Comment: _In near hydraulic equilibrium_, unless there are several kinds of `near-equilibrium,` as a technical term, and `hydraulic` is one of them.

Comment: Writing advice requests are off topic. Please see the [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're referencing the state of an object's natural buoyancy in water. In this case, it may make more sense to say "near hydraulic equilibrium" as hydraulic equilibrium is a phrase that loses its meaning when the individual words are split apart. It's more natural to say that an object is near its point of natural buoyancy.